# how to modify this code to transfer files faster?

Tags: python, sockets, file-transfer

I wrote that simple client/server code in order to transfer files.
the code transferred pictures and text files pretty easily and very fast. but it takes a long time to transfer an mp4 file (more than 10 minutes). how do I modify it to run faster? thank you

the server:

```py
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))

s.listen(10)
c, addr = s.accept()
print('{} connected.'.format(addr))

f = open("test.png", "rb")
l = os.path.getsize("test.png")
m = f.read(l)
c.sendall(m)
f.close()
print("Done sending...")
```

and the client:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

f = open("received.jpg", "wb")
data = None
while True:
    m = s.recv(1024)
    data = m
    if m:
        while m:
            m = s.recv(1024)
            data += m
        else:
            break
f.write(data)
f.close()
print("Done receiving")
```

Comment: That while loop in the client looks awkward at best. I don't know how much of a difference it will make but on the client side there's no benefit to building up the `data` bytes object and then writing it all out at the end. Just call `f.write(m)` each time through a simplified while loop. Also you might try using slightly larger buffers, say 8k or 16k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as you receive and with a larger buffer.

Also use `with` to ensure the socket and file are closed.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))

with s, open("received.jpg", "wb") as f:
    while data := s.recv(1024*1024):
        f.write(data)

print("Done receiving")
```